# Multithreading vs concurency

Tags: java, многопоточность

В чем разница между понятиями multithreading, concurency, parallelism разве это не одно и тоже

Comment: @SviatVolkov concurrency - это тоже "термин общего характера", а пакет просто назван, потому что для этого предназначен :)

Comment: @AlexChermenin спасибо, удалил свой некорректный коммент)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Multithreading** (многопоточность) - это использование нескольких потоков. При этом вовсе *не* обязательно, что эти потоки будут выполняться *одновременно* (параллельно). В эру одноядерных процессоров многопоточность тоже активно использовалась, например, в приложениях с GUI: тяжёлые вычисления выносятся в отдельный поток, чтобы не "замерзал" gui-поток. При этом понятно, что эти потоки выполняются по очереди, не одновременно.

**Parallelism** (параллелизм, параллельность) - это использование нескольких потоков *одновременно*. Это возможно *только* в системах с несколькими ядрами/процессорами. Запускаются несколько потоков и они выполняются каждый на своём собственном ядре.

**Concurrency** (с переводом этого термина на русский язык есть определённые проблемы: его переводят как *параллельность*, *одновременность*, *конкуренция*) - это возможный одновременный доступ к каким-либо ресурсам: памяти, файлам и т. п. Обычно это происходит в результате обращения к ресурсу из нескольких потоков. Естественно, один поток может испортить (перезаписать) результат выполнения другого потока. Чтобы этого не произошло, приходится использовать *синхронизацию*.

**Asynchrony** (асинхронность) - асинхронный доступ к каким-либо ресурсам. Потоки при этом могут не использоваться вовсе. Например, операции ввода-вывода (IO) могут выполняться таким образом. Один единственный поток может инициировать чтение/запись с помощью асинхронного IO сразу во много файлов, сокетов и т. п.

Comment: @alexander-petrovразве можно не использовать потоки и выполнять операции вне какого либо потока